# Frame Navigation Problem?

Tags: animation, keyframes, error, pose-mode

When I try to drag the frame viewing slider along the frame container while in pose mode, the model deforms. It continues to move even if I drag the slider to it's original position, meaning that the more I move it, the more it twists. When I go to edit mode and back to pose mode, the model resets to the correct position. Why is this happening?
[image: Original Position]

[image: Frame 80]

[image: Back to original frame]

Comment: Do you have any unusual drivers, handlers, addons or registered scripts installed? Could be something trying to automatically manipulate the model on scene refresh. Try disabling all such things and see if the problem persists.

Comment: What is "the frame viewing slider"?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a dependency cycle. Look in the Python console to see if a dependency cycle error is reported there.

Comment: @dr.Sybren aka the TIMELINE window.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by remaking the armature, I think Ray Mairlot was right about a dependency cycle issue.
[Ray Mairlot](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/241/ray-mairlot)